# Chunking big class for serialization

Tags: c#, serialization

I am having a problem I've got a big class, in that class Ive 4 properties that contains other class, ant that class contain various lists and models(simple class with properties)

Class looks like:

```
[Serializable]
public class BackupProject 
{
    public DocumentSet Documents;
    public CompareSet MetaData;
    public RelationshipSet Relationships;
    public Dictionary<string, ItemConfig> DocumentData;
}
```

To serialize I'm using :

```
using (FileStream stream = File.Open(fullPath + "/" + backupFile, FileMode.Create))
{
     stream.Position= 0;
     var bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
     using (ZipOutputStream zipStream = new ZipOutputStream(stream))
     {
           zipStream.SetLevel(9);
           ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry("BackupProject") {DateTime = DateTime.Now};
           zipStream.PutNextEntry(zipEntry);
           bformatter.Serialize(zipStream, documents);
     }
}
```

As you see I tried data compression and still I am getting:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException "The internal
>   array cannot expand to greater than Int32.MaxValue elements."

That's why I need to chunk up this class, But have no idea how to do it witch such irregular class content.

Comment: In what line does this exception happen?

Comment: bformatter.Serialize(zipStream, documents); in this line

Comment: maybe you can Serialize your class as XML and then convert it to Binary,depending on what you are doing wit your serialized class

Comment: Perhaps this would be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569127/serializationexception-when-serializing-lots-of-objects-in-net

Comment: Hmm, maybe but I need a little bit of explanation to that code, never used that :)

Comment: We can't answer that question without seeing your contained types including `DocumentSet`, `CompareSet`, `Relationships` and `ItemConfig`.  Can you share them?  Most importantly, *which of them contain references to other objects in the graph*?  But you could start with http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2007/07/serializing-lots-of-different-objects.html